# How can I integrate a value into a variable's name in a for loop?

Tags: r, function

I am writing a function to import a large number of dBase files into separate dataframes. These files' name have all the same structure: XYZ_[id]. For example, XYZ_3456, XYZ_8765, XYZ_2468, and so on. In the function, I would like to import them one by one using a *for* loop and create a dataframe which name includes the id. Their ids (ex. 3456, 8765, 2468) are stored into a list.

I would like to do something like:

```
for (i in liste) {
  df_#i# <-read.dbf("C:/Users/M/temp/XYZ_#i#.dbf")
}
```

where #i# means "insert value of i here".

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
ids = 10:20 # HERE YOU HAVE TO CREATE A VECTOR WITH THE ID YOU NEED TO LOAD!
your.path = "C:/Users/M/temp"

for (i in ids)
{
  temp.load = paste("XYX", i, sep = "_")
  temp.load = paste(temp.name, "dbf", sep = ".")
  temp.load = paste(your.path, temp.name, sep = "/")
  
  name.df = paste("df", i, sep = "_")
  
  assign(name.df, read.dbf(temp.load)
}
```

I do not have your databases, so I could not test the code. Also, for simplicity I just used id ranging from 10 to 20. You need to modify the object `ids` by creating a vector with the id you need to import.

Comment: Thank you. It works perfectly once adapted to my data.

Comment: You are welcome :) Consider upvoting and accepting my answer, if your problem is solved.